# Scala - omit parentheses from apply method for a DSL

Tags: scala, dsl, apply

I'm trying to create a DSL and running into a problem.  I have these definitions:

```
case class Var(name: String)
case class Lam(v: Var, t: Var)
val (a, b) = (Var("a"), Var("b"))
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
scala> \ a b
Lam(Var(a),Var(b))
```

Reading up on the rules of parenthesis dropping, I see that I need to chain functions that take one parameter each, so I've created a series of "builder" classes that perform the construction:

```
class LamBuilderB(v: Var) {
    def apply(t: Var) = Lam(v, t)
}

class LamBuilderA {
    def apply(v: Var) = new LamBuilderB(v)
}

val \ = new LamBuilderA
```

I had hoped this would work since each `apply` takes only one argument.  But, it doesn't seem like dropping the parentheses is legal for `apply` since it wants to treat the argument as a method name:

```
scala> \(a)(b)
res95: Lam = Lam(Var(a),Var(b))

scala> \ a b
error: value a is not a member of LamBuilderA
    \ a b
      ^
```

Any ideas how how I can get the DSL syntax without parentheses?

*Bonus Question*: Can I get this?:

```
scala> \a.b
Lam(Var(a),Var(b))
```

Comment: I certainly _hope_ you can't get `\a.b`!  Overloading `.` is not what I would call a good idea for an embedded DSL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get pretty close using one of 4 unary prefix operators (`~`, `!`, `+`, `-`):

```
trait Expr {
    def &(other: Expr) = Lam(this, other)
    def unary_~ = this
}

case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
case class Lam(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr

scala> ~ Var("a") & Var("b")
res0: Lam = Lam(Var(a),Var(b))

scala> ~ Var("a") & Var("b") & Var("c")
res1: Lam = Lam(Lam(Var(a),Var(b)),Var(c))
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer.  I think I'm going to have to stick with `\(a,b)` as my syntax, but taking advantage of a unary operator is a good idea.